# Why is this returning the error .contains() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, frontend

Am getting the error .contains() is not a function. Full code is [here](https://github.com/3noki/project_6_react_neighborhood_map/blob/master/src/App.js), probably too much to paste here so here's the relevant bits. Locations is globally set as well as query, then set state in the component.

*edit, o is the individual location, there are 5 titles and long/latitutes from the json file

```
let locationslist = this.state.locations
.filter(o => o.contains(this.state.query))
.map(o => <li key={o}
  type="button"
  className="btn"
  id="filterMarker"
  tabIndex="0">{o}</li>)

render() {
return (
<div>
  <div id="filtercontainer">
  <input
    id="filterbar"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Filter"
    onChange={this.handleQueryChange} value={this.state.query} />
    <ul>
    {this.state.locationslist}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="map" />
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: What is the `o` in the first filter method? Your data is coming via an asynchronous job, but aside from that `contains` is used for DOM nodes I think.

Comment: I tried includes() and I get the same error. o is location, locations should be filtering out 5 individual locations

Comment: As you can see you are getting answers blindly :) So, it is better for updating your question and sharing all the data types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like locations is a simple Javascript object from JSON. Are you looking for a specific key? If so, I'd go with `o => o[this.state.query]`. If you're looking for the title match, I'd go with `o => o.title.contains(this.state.query)` or even better, make it case insensitive with `o => o.title.toLowerCase().contains(this.state.query.toLowerCase())`

Comment: I want to iterate over the locations from the data that comes from the json file, and create a li element for each, then they filtered with the title match.

Answer (score 42):

You are calling `contains` on your location object. Did you mean to check if the title contains the query string?

Try `o.title.includes(this.state.query)` instead.

`contains` appears to be [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains). You should use `includes` instead.

Comment: Okay I will use includes instead. 

Yes, I do want to check if the title contains the query string to filter the li elements.

If I use o.title.includes(this.state.query), I get the error "objects are not valid as a React child ". Can you somehow use filter to iterate over locations like locations[i].title?

Comment: I cloned your project and without ever having touched React before I can see a lot of things which are seriously wrong. Those issues are not related to the initial question you posted here (the error you encountered and asked about is fixed by what I proposed). I suppose you put a little bit more effort into your project and try to fix the remaining issues. Feel free to post follow-up questions if you get stuck.

Comment: I was confused because `contains` works in my browser for strings but not in NodeJS. Thanks. Using `includes`.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling an array method on a Obj not and array

Answer (score 2):

You need to check exact property of the object. Contains will work only on strings or simple array, not array of abject. Should try like object.searchingProperty.Constains(searchingText);

Comment: .contains() is not an object method - it is for DOM Node classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains